# How to update component information in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, async-await, axios

I'm consuming the data from this api, using useEffect.
What I want, is that every time the data changes in the API. Change component information

```
const [infoUser, setInfoUser] = useState([]);
const getInfoUser = async () => {
    try {
      const accessToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@access_token');

      axios
        .get(
          'https://apiexample.com/cliete',
          {
            headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` },
          },
        )
        .then(function (response) {
          // handle success
          console.log('DADOS USER:', response.data.data);
          const userData = response.data.data;

          setInfoUser([...infoUser, userData]);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          // handle error
          console.log(error);
        });
    } catch (e) {
      // error reading value
      console.log('Erro de token', e);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getInfoUser();
  }, []);
```

On another screen, I change the data and save.

But the previous screen has not been updated.
The data only changes when I log out and enter the app again

```
{infoUser.map(user => (
            <Text style={styles.subtitle}>Nome Completo</Text>
            <Text style={styles.title}>{user.nomeCompleto}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ))}
```

Comment: Http does not have the power to automatically know when data on the server has changed. You either have to use axios to fetch server data every now and then (polling), or use a different internet protocol designed for realtime data flow. If you want to do that with react, you can look into graphql over websocket. This is a big paradigm change from http, so a in a typical use case, you might have to rewrite both server and client from scratch.

Answer (score 3):

If you pass variables/functions to `useEffect` array of dependencies, and they are changing, it will trigger your `useEffect`. So if you want to depend on some `data` you can write it like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  getInfoUser();
}, [data]);
```

Every time `data` is updated `useEffect` will be called by React.

Comment: When I pass userData in useEffect. I get the error: userData is not defined.              
 userData is return from the api with the information

Comment: so based on what do you want to fetch data, what should trigger your useEffect? Or you just want fresh data? Then maybe you need just to run it every 1 minute ?

Comment: I just want the new data.

When I enter screen 1, I must return the current API data (what is already happening)

On another screen, I can update the data (Screen 2). When I update the data on Screen 2. It doesn't change on Screen 1